# How to properly format a POST API request with JSON?

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio

I have teaching myself how to develop Android applications and I recently started using the Volley library for networking. I have been able to send basic requests with it. I was experimenting with Pocket's API to see if my app could fetch the items. Their [documentation page](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication) mentions that I have to send a JSON request like so

```
POST /v3/oauth/request HTTP/1.1
Host: getpocket.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Accept: application/json
{"consumer_key":"1234-abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234",
"redirect_uri":"pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"}
```

So I made a JSONObject in my app, added the key `consumer_key` with the value of my consumer key, then added in the key `redirect_uri` with its respective value. I sent this JSONObject as a request to the required URL as a POST request using Volley. The response code I received was 403, which is caused by a bad consumer key. I have double-checked the consumer key, so the problem lies with my request. How should I go about making the JSON request? Do I have to add the extra data, like Content-Type? If so, how?

If it is not too much, could you point me to a beginner-friendly resource on JSON, since I do not have much knowledge about web development?
Thank you.

Comment: `{"consumer_key":"1234-abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234",
"redirect_uri":"pocketapp1234:authorizationFinished"}` is header or body ?

Comment: First, use curl command to do this post request with your consumer_key, make sure the key is correct. Second, parse your JSONObject codes.

Answer (score 0):

What request methode do you use on your code? I am facing issue when using StringRequest method. Its work when use JsonObjectRequest method.

Here is how to create request besides on my experience.

### Create Header Parameter

```
final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers.put("X-Accept", "application/json");
headers.put("consumer_key", "your-consumer-key");
headers.put("redirect_uri", "https://kamus.nusagates.com");
```

### Create [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) From headers

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(headers);
```

### Create JsonObjectRequest

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               //get all response data
                Log.d("respon", String.valueOf(response));
                try {
                    //get code from response
                    Log.d("respon code", response.getString("code"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String server = String.valueOf(response.headers);
                Log.d("header", server);
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
        };
```

### Add the request to The Queue

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

May this could help you solve your problem.

Cheers